# WebRTC (Video Calling) for Cordova

Tags: cordova, webrtc, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, video-conferencing

I'm working on video calling in my cordova application. Kindly suggest me the best WebRTC to use in my application for video calling.

Comment: try https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-cordova.

Answer (score 0):

you can try vidyo.io PaaS it's very simple to integrate https://vidyo.io